# IPA not getting installed in ios 8 version

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

My Client gave me two UDID's of two different iPad devices. One has iOS 7 and other has iOS 8. I added both the UDID's carefully in provisional profile. I created an ipa file in Xcode 5.1 and gave the ipa file to client. The problem is ipa is installing in iOS 7 device but not in iOS 8. What could be the problem ?

Comment: Is there any error occurred during IPA install? Are you installing the IPA via iTunes along with Provisioning Profile?

Comment: No I used this site http://www.diawi.com/ and gave the link to client

Comment: app not getting installed. It starts to install and a failure msg is displayed

Comment: what kind of failure message?

Comment: Failed to install the ipa

Answer (score 1):

Just now i am also faced this issue. But it was solved. I created provisional AdHoc  distribution certificate. In Build phases, select provisional profile as adhoc certificate after that you can your create archive file through adhoc distribution. Now save the ipa and share to your clients.